Strapi Redis cache invalidation on entity update
I'm facing an issue with Redis caching. When one entity in the Strapi collection is modified, Redis removes the entire cache for that entity and everything gets reset.
Maybe it's because we're using the REST API? I'll leave the libraries we're using on the project:
"strapi-plugin-redis": "1.0.1",
"strapi-plugin-rest-cache": "4.2.8",
"strapi-provider-rest-cache-redis": "4.2.8"

The only thing I've found for solving this problem through the strapi-plugin-rest-cache is to add a 'key' in the config > provider > key: 'key'. But that doesn't seem to be helping.

Can you intercept the stream of commands sent to Redis, to see why it behaves in the way that it does?
